# c# Trying to download a file with WebClient that contains a special character in filename

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download a file with a special character **'Ç'** for example in the filename, I get an exception with that character in the URL string.

**System.Net.WebException

HResult=0x80131509

Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Source=System.Net.Requests**

For example: [http://www.somesite.com/abcdç.pdf](http://www.somesite.com/abcd%C3%A7.pdf) would create an exception in the WebClient. What is another way to download files using URI or how can I fix this exception?

Here's some sample code:

```
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] archiveData = wc.DownloadData("http://www.somesite.com/abcdç.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, what is `client` and what is `wc`?  Are they really the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Uri encoding for the special character, eg.

```
www.somesite.com/abcd%C3%A7.pdf
```

You can get a safe Uri like this

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/abcdç.pdf");
byte[] archiveData = wc.DownloadData(u.AbsoluteUri);
```

`u.AbsoluteUri` will give you an encoded URI.